# how to build query with several manyTomany relationships - Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I really don't understand all the ways to build the right query.

I have the following models in the code i'm working on. I can't change models.

models/FollowUp:

```
class FollowUp(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, blank=True, )
```

models/Survey:

class Survey(BaseModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

```
followup = models.ManyToManyField(
    FollowUp, blank=True, help_text='questionnaires')

user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, through='SurveyStatus')
```

models/SurveyStatus:

```
class SurveyStatus(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    survey_status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                     blank=True,
                                     null=True,
                                     choices=STATUS_SURVEY_CHOICES,
                                     )
```

models/UserSurvey:

```
class UserSurvey(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True,
                             on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    followups = models.ManyToManyField(FollowUp, blank=True)
    surveys = models.ManyToManyField(Survey, blank=True)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, blank=True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, user_id):
        user = User.objects.filter(pk=user_id).first()
        cu_quest = cls(user=user)
        cu_quest.save()
        cu_quest._get_all_active_surveys
        cu_quest._get_all_followups()
        cu_quest._get_all_questions()
        return cu_quest

    def _get_all_questions(self):
        [[self.questions.add(ques) for ques in qstnr.questions.all()]
         for qstnr in self.followups.all()]
        return

    def _get_all_followups(self):
        queryset = FollowUp.objects.filter(survey__user=self.user).filter(survey__user__surveystatus_survey_status='active')

        # queryset = self._get_all_active_surveys()

        [self.followups.add(quest) for quest in queryset]
        return

    @property
    def _get_all_active_surveys(self):
        queryset = Survey.objects.filter(user=self.user, 
                   surveystatus__survey_status='active')
        [self.surveys.add(quest) for quest in queryset]
        return
```

Now my questions:

1. my view sends to the create of the UserSurvey model in order to create a questionary.
   I need to get all the questions of the followup of the surveys with a survey_status = 'active' for the user (the one who clicks on a button)...
   I tried several things:

- I wrote the _get_all_active_surveys() function and there I get all the surveys that are with a survey_status = 'active' and then the _get_all_followups() function needs to call it to use the result to build its own one. I have an issue telling me that

> a list is not a callable object.

- I tried to write directly the right query in _get_all_followups() with

  queryset = FollowUp.objects.filter(survey__user=self.user).filter(survey__user__surveystatus_survey_status='active')

but I don't succeed to manage all the M2M relationships. I wrote the query above but issue also

> Related Field got invalid lookup: surveystatus_survey_status

2. i read that a related_name can help to build reverse query but i don't understand why?
3. it's the first time i see return empty and what it needs to return above. Why this notation?

If you have clear explanations (more than the doc) I will very appreciate.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things to answer here, I've put them into a list:

1. Your `_get_all_active_surveys` has the `@property` decorator but neither of the other two methods do? It isn't actually a property so I would remove it.
2. You are using a list comprehension to add your queryset objects to the m2m field, this is unnecessary as you don't actually want a list object and can be rewritten as e.g. `self.surveys.add(*queryset)`
3. You can comma-separate filter expressions as `.filter(expression1, expression2)` rather than `.filter(expression1).filter(expression2)`.
4. You are missing an underscore in `surveystatus_survey_status` it should be `surveystatus__survey_status`.
5. Related name is just another way of reverse-accessing relationships, it doesn't actually change how the relationship exists - by default Django will do something like `ModelA.modelb_set.all()` - you can do `reverse_name="my_model_bs"` and then `ModelA.my_model_bs.all()`

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply.
I didn't understand what to do because it looks like you want to mix 2 solutions. or i use the _get_all_active_surveys() function to get the result of _get_all_followups() function  or i use the query with queryset = FollowUp.objects.filter(survey__user=self.user).filter(survey__user__surveystatus___survey_status='active').

the first solution with the function gave me this error
add() argument after * must be an iterable, not NoneType

the second
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'survey_set'


and why the return is after the list to send?

Comment: and also it's impossible my own _get_all_active_survey(self) like this
queryset = self. _get_all_active_survey()

i have the following error
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Well `_get_all_active_surveys` returns None, so it shouldn't be a property. I'm not suggested mixing things up, just being consistent with what your methods are doing. Do you want them to add m2m relations or return querysets? I would suggest any function that starts with `get_` should return things and `set_` should set values.

Comment: ok but still what is the solution to my issue?
I removed the @property and then?
if it's a get it has to get the result and be used in the second function. For example, I get the result from _get_all_active_surveys and I should use it in the function _get_all_followups() 
but it didn't work
what i get from self.surveys.add(*queryset) is None and I know that queryset is not None

Comment: Well your `_get_all_active_surveys` function returns None, bump the `return` up to align with the list comprehension and it will return a list of your objects

Comment: hello
i already aligned the statement to the return to get explicit result but it doesn't still work. the issue is the following is this statement in _get_all_questions(self) :
[[self.questions.add(ques) for ques in qstnr.questions.all()] for qstnr in self.followups.all()]

i want to get the questions only on the followup got from _get_all_followups(self)
so i tried:
return [[self.questions.add(ques) for ques in qstnr.questions.all()] for qstnr in self._get_all_followups()]
but i have issue also TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
don't get the point

Comment: Does `_get_all_followups` have the `@property` decorator?

Comment: no i removed that but with or without it didn't work